# Conservation of volume debit

Tags: fluid-dynamics, conservation-laws

Suppose that we have a perfect, incompressible liquid, whose flow is depicted in the diagram below:[image]

Where $Q_1,Q_2,Q_3$ are the (constant) volume flows and $h$ is the height of the cylindrical recipient (of diameter $D$).

When attempting to derive a relation for $\frac{dh}{dt}$, I was initially concerned about whether it is possible at all for it to be non-zero and the liquid to be incompressible due to the following argument:

$\begin{equation}
\rho = const \implies div(\vec{v}) = 0 \implies V_{in} = V_{out}
\end{equation}$

Which would therefore suggest that $h$ must be constant. However, I think that this is wrong because of the changing control volume (as the above relation applies to a fixed control volume), and that in fact the argument should be :

$\begin{equation}
\rho = const \implies div(\vec{v}) = 0 \implies V_{in} - V_{out} = \Delta_{Control Volume}
\end{equation}$

$\begin{equation}
\implies Q_1dt + Q_3dt - Q_2dt = \pi (\frac{D}{2})^2 dh
\end{equation}$

which would enable the liquid to remain incompressible and for $h$ to change. Is this the correct reasoning?

Comment: Sometimes it's useful to take a limiting case.  Suppose two of the Q's approach zero, and one remains finite.

Comment: Yes, it is the correct reasoning.  Input - Output = Accumulation